# Benchmarking tool

Tags: apachebench, against, httperf

I'm unable to decide which is a better benchmarking tool-Is it apachebench tool or httperf?
Please help me to decide which one would be the most appropriate tool to be chosen for benchmarking the web application.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/900875/is-ab-or-httperf-better-for-checking-performance-of-a-website

Answer (score 6):

I suppose it depends on what kind of testing you want to do.
ApacheBench basically tests a general load, but httperf gives more a surgical precision and can simulate real user activity.

- [is “ab” or “httperf” better for checking performance of a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/900875/is-ab-or-httperf-better-for-checking-performance-of-a-website)
- [How do you test the performance of a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53738/how-do-you-test-the-performance-of-a-website)
- [Most effective and realistic free web-app load tester?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772524/most-effective-and-realistic-free-web-app-load-tester)
- [Tools to benchmark web-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449169/tools-to-benchmark-web-services)

Answer (score 2):

They're both good for doing different types of testing.  httperf will just send a barage of data to your server, whether or not it's answered.  That gives you the breaking point of your app, and shows you how it fails out.  Use this to find bottlenecks.

apachebench is a bit different in that it sends exactly what you tell it, and is more typically used to measure response times (for example, if you optimize). Once the bottlenecks are found and fixed, check the speed with this.

*Please Note: That's what I do, but I'm not a master*

Answer (score 2):

> I'm unable to decide which is a better
>   benchmarking tool-Is it apachebench
>   tool or httperf?

There is an extensive discussion about the benefit of each tool here:

http://dsec.com/en_apachebench_httperf.html

The guy went as far as to write a wrapper (public domain C code) around Apache Benchmark and HTTPerf to illustrate the pro and cons of each solution.

He also explains how to make sure system settings will not make the benchmark fail, and how to get the most of a server machine (OS, virtualization, etc.).

Hope this helps!